# Principle of free() function C

Tags: c, nested, structure, free

I'm using free() as intended to free the memory occupied by some variable in my case it's struct with more or less following construction:

```
struct mystruct{
   int firstparam;
   string secondparam;
   struct someOtherSimpleStruct* otherstruct;
```

the main point is that inside the struct there is other simple (no more nested structs) struct. I just want to make sure that I do understand the way of functioning free() correctly. If I call free with mystruct pointer as an argument the memory will be cleaned just on the first level, so the memory occupied by mystruct = size of int, string and the pointer itself, no other data stored inside someother struct won't be freed and to achieve it the only way is to recursively iterate throughout the whole nested structure? Or maybe there is any universal function which can free a memory of the whole nested structure?

Comment: Yes, you must `free()` the memory in the reverse order (not necessarily *exact* but before the containing object goes out of life). For every `malloc()` you need a `free()`.

Comment: As with *any other resource*... if your struct held a `FILE *`, for example. You'd need to *close* that file before you deallocate the structure...

Comment: _Or maybe there is any universal function which can free a memory of the whole nested structure?_  [alloca](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html)  allocates memory that is automatically freed (not standard) and you don't need to call `free` when you reserve space with it,  but notice that the function allocates space in the stack and If the allocation causes stack overflow the program behavior is undefined.

Comment: @DavidRanieri If alloca is an option, then probably VLA is an option too. With the advantages of VLA being standardized and with better type safety.

Comment: @Lundin true, but a VLA is a data structure not a function.

Comment: It might be worth noting that freeing nested structures is one of the things that can be done easily and automatically in **C++**. So if this is important for you, you *might* want to consider upgrading. However there is a learning curve.

Comment: @user253751: Not so much a learning curve as, "if you want to do it right, *forget basically everything you learned so far* and start from scratch". Very little of what you learned in C will help you in C++, and a lot (arrays, pointers, implementing data structures manually, ...) will be actively harmful.

Comment: @DevSolar It is perfectly fine to treat C++ as "C with a few extra useful bits". That is a design goal of C++. Transitioning to C++ that way is not "wrong", and pretending it is is mostly just elitism.

Comment: @user253751 After about 20 years of working on C++ maintenance, I very much disagree. To me, "C plus something" is at the core of C++ being considered a "hard" language. Ref. [Stop teaching C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) by Kate Gregory. (Sorry for the repost, for some reason YT *keeps* giving me a link into the *middle* of that talk.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so the memory occupied by mystruct = size of int, string and the pointer itself, no other data stored inside someother struct won't be freed

Correct, because no other data is stored inside the struct. You have a pointer to data stored *elsewhere* though.

> to achieve it the only way is to recursively iterate throughout the whole nested structure?

Yes. Free whatever `otherstruct` points at before freeing the surrounding struct, if this is the only pointer referring to that dynamically allocated memory.

> Or maybe there is any universal function which can free a memory of the whole nested structure?

No such thing exists.

Comment: And this would be one of several reasons why linked list-like data types using dynamic memory are very slow and cumbersome to work with. In general, anything based on multiple repeated calls to malloc/realloc/free will perform poorly. Better to over allocate large chunks of data and only realloc another large chunk, once you actually run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Since `free()` receives a `void*`, it has no idea what the allocated space contains or how it is structured. Therefore it cannot release memory recursively.